# SIGTERM with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: terminal, process, console, kill, signal

I know that inside a terminal, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> keyboard shortcut will send a `SIGINT` signal to the current foreground process. Is there a way to setup a keyboard shortcut for sending `SIGTERM` or even `SIGKILL` to the current process? I think it could save me some time.

I'm running `Ubuntu 11.04`

Comment: Relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/362559/43390

Answer (score 36):

stty is responsible for controlling this, you may already have one setup.  You can check by doing:

```
$ stty -e
speed 38400 baud; 53 rows; 225 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe echok echoke -echonl echoctl
        -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
        -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
        -ignbrk brkint -inpck ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd -hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts
        -dsrflow -dtrflow -mdmbuf
discard dsusp   eof     eol     eol2    erase   intr    kill    lnext   
^O      ^Y      ^D      <undef> <undef> ^?      ^C      ^U      ^V      
min     quit    reprint start   status  stop    susp    time    werase  
1       ^\      ^R      ^Q      ^@      ^S      ^Z      0       ^W
```

The last few lines should look familiar, ^C=intr is the one you mentioned in your question.  You can read how to set more via:

```
$ man stty
```

Comment: `$ stty -e` is [BSD](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=stty&sektion=1), for Ubuntu use `$ stty -a`, to see: `intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D;`

Comment: I'm interested in hooking a signal for status, so I'm wondering about the 'status' keystroke, "ctrl-@".  Is that a signal?

Comment: The shortcut `^\ ` sends `SIGQUIT`.

Answer (score 25):

The set of available signals for a tty are `SIGINT` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), `SIGTSTP` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) and `SIGQUIT` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>). You can assign different characters to them, but those are the only available signals. For your purposes you may be able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> to send `SIGQUIT`, although it acts like an error and causes a core dump by default. You can use the `stty` command to see and change the settings.

Comment: I had to search surprisingly long to find the Ctrl+\ shortcut again. Thanks a lot! This is very useful as it still works when the process is not reacting to Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 23):

> I know that inside a terminal, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> keyboard shortcut will send a SIGINT signal to the current foreground process.

Your knowledge is incorrect on two points:

1. The signal is sent to the foreground *process group*.
2. It's only <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> if that is the special character that happens to be configured at the time.  (That's the default on most modern systems, but historically it could have been the `DEL` character or something else.)

> Is there a way to setup a keyboard shortcut for sending SIGTERM or even SIGKILL to the current process?

No.  The line discipline controls what signals are sent, and those signals are hardwired.  They are (in a standard Unix) `SIGHUP`, `SIGINT`, `SIGTTOU`, `SIGTTIN`, `SIGQUIT`, and `SIGTSTP`.  There are no others generated by the line discipline.

Answer (score 3):

Though you can edit your keybindings with [`stty -a`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html), it's not possible to create a `SIGTERM` or `SIGKILL` keybinding that will interact with your process.

Read more about it [here](https://superuser.com/a/417991/1004400).