# send SIGTERM with command line shortcut

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to be able to send the SIGTERM signal with a command line shortcut, like I can send SIGINT with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

I ve read before about <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, but that does not work here, nothing happen.

I also read this SO [SIGTERM with a keyboard shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/343031/sigterm-with-a-keyboard-shortcut).

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 43; columns 123; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q;
stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -extproc
```

Is quit the signal i want to trigger?
Is kill the signal i want to trigger?

And very stupidly... How to input that '^\' or '^U' in my keyboard? I shall just type it then press enter?

Comment: `^U` means Ctrl+U, I think.

Comment: probably yes, but the behavior is so weird. I type ctrl+Y it prints ^Y on the console, then i type ctrl+U, it erase the line : /

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6764265/1959808

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, `SIGTERM` cannot be sent from the command line, as noted at: https://superuser.com/a/343611/199930.

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/362559/43390

Answer (score 28):

It's not entirely true that you can't send `SIGTERM` from the command line. [You can't send it from a keyboard shortcut](https://superuser.com/a/417991/1004400), but you *can* send it from the command line.

Based on the [man-page for kill](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/kill1.html), you are able to send a `SIGTERM` to any process. You would accomplish this by finding your process in the process table (type `ps`) and then typing `kill -15 [pid]`.

Here is a list of the keyboard shortcuts that you can use in a terminal to handle processes:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends `SIGINT` which asks to interrupt a program but can be caught or ignored.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> sends `SIGTSTP` which asks to pause a program but can be caught or ignored. This process can be resumed later.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> sends `SIGQUIT` which is the same as `SIGINT` except it also produces a core dump.

[Source 1](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html) and [Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042201/how-does-sigint-relate-to-the-other-termination-signals-such-as-sigterm-sigquit)

Comment: Note that the default signal sent by `kill` is `SIGTERM`, so your `kill` command could just be `kill [pid]`.

Comment: Ctrl+\ for `SIGQUIT` worked for me on OS X (an application was catching `SIGINT`), thank you!

Comment: `kill -15 <pid>` or `kill -s SIGTERM <pid>`